(Flutter) Asset Images couldn't be preloaded because current context is null
I'm encountering an issue with preloading asset images in my Flutter app. My goal is to preload all asset images before the app starts to ensure smoother user experience. However, I keep running into a problem where the context is null when trying to preload the images, even after trying different approaches to obtain the current context. This is my code:
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

void main() async {
  WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
   await preloadImages();
   FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: []);

    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme.theme,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      translations: TranslationService(),
      locale: locale.initLocale,
      fallbackLocale: const Locale('en'),
      initialBinding: AppBindings(),
      initialRoute:
          pref.getValue('id') == null ? AppRoutes.welcome : AppRoutes.home,
      getPages: AppPages.pages,
    );
  }
}
Future<void> preloadImages() async {
  BuildContext? context = navigatorKey.currentContext;
  if (context != null) {
    for (String asset in allAsset) {
      await precacheImage(AssetImage(asset), context);
    }
  } else {
    print("Current context is null. Images couldn't be preloaded.");
  }
}
final List<String> allAsset = [
  'assets/images/user.png',
  'assets/images/twitter.png',
  'assets/images/logo2.png',
  .....
];


You called preloadImages before runApp, and of course, context is not available yet. I think you should move it to initState of the very first screen (welcome or home in your case), where context is ready, and dismiss splash screen (FlutterNativeSplash.remove) after that

you are preloading images before runnig GetMaterialApp that's why it is not getting context because navigatorKey is assigned yet.
For loading images, make your "MyApp" to statefulWidget and then in initState() Method call preloadImage function with Future.Delay with minimum 50 miliseconds so that you can get the context from navigatorKey.
